# Defined an ajax function in my urls.py file, but getting a 404 when invoking it in a test

Tags: python, ajax, django, python-3.x, python-unittest

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I have this in my urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^ajax/calculate_taxes/$', post, name='calculate_taxes'), 
]
```

However, I'm getting a 404 when I try and invoke the logic in my test_views.py class ...

```
# Basic test to verify we can get valid return data
def test_calculate_tax(self):
    state = 'MN'
    gross = 100000
    salary = 75000
    json_data = json.dumps({'state': state,
                            'gross': gross,
                            'salary': salary})

    response = self.client.post('/ajax/calculate_taxes/', json_data,
                                content_type='application/json',
                                HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH='XMLHttpRequest')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)  # this is OK.
    print(response.content)
    self.assertEqual(response.content, 2)
```

The view contains a simple post function

```
def post(request):
    state = request.GET.get('state', None)
    gross_income = request.GET.get('gross', None)
    owner_salary = request.GET.get('salary', None)

    data = {
        'sole_pr_taxes': TaxCalculatorService.calc_sole_pr_taxes(state, gross_income),
        's_corp_taxes': TaxCalculatorService.calc_s_corp_taxes(state, gross_income, owner_salary),
    }
```

What am I doing wrong that is causing the 404 in my test?

Comment: Looks ok to me. Have you tried `reverse_lazy('calculate_taxes')` for url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used a regex in a `path` call; it's interpreting the `^` and `$` characters literally. It should be just:

```
path('ajax/calculate_taxes/', post, name='calculate_taxes'),
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a JsonResponse

```
return JsonResponse(data)
```